# Divider is not showing on top of first element in ExpandableListView Android

Tags: android

I am using `ExpandableListView` and everything is working fine. But one thing is really annoying that it is not showing `divider` on top of first element as shown in picture below. Any suggestion will be highly apprciated

[image]

Comment: This is how divider should be i guess . There is nothing to divide on top because its the first item .

Comment: @ADM yeah but now I need to show as its requirement, so what is the work around to achieve this goal. I can put border on top but then i will have to keep track so that when user open the first element then I will have to hide the border and viceversa, which i think is not a good practice

Comment: You have to have border in the Item Layout . just be aware it will merge with order of next item and then next divider will be thicker . so u have to handle it . maybe show the Upper border only for 0th index.

Answer (score 0):

Dividers are placed at bottom like they should be, not on top of an item. There is workaround for this. Create divider inside your `Drawable` folder like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/backgroundGray" />
</shape>
```

Give it the color you want.

Now inside your XML where your `ExpandableListView` is do something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/divider_gray"/>
    
    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider_gray"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This way, you will have a divider on top of the `ExpandableListView` and also `ExpandableListView` will have that same divider in between items.

Answer (score 0):

For `ListView` the divider will only show **between the items**, which means you won't see the divider neither **on top of the first item** nor **on bottom of the last item**.

If you want to show the divider on top of the first item, you can add a `View` of `width="match_parent"`, `height="1dp"` and `background="@color/your_color"` above the `ListView`.